# DAX to determine quantity of a product in stock for Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Power BI I'm looking to graph the stock of a product over time.  I in essence only have one product, and the table that's stored in has a line for each instance of that item.

An abbreviated example of that table is:
ID
Volume
DateIn
DateOut

I'm trying to figure out the best approach of graphing the daily stock of this.  I have a date table that's related to DateIn (which I'm unsure of).  I've tried creating a measure to determine if the row is in stock, given the filter context.

I'm debating if this needs to be a separate table, used only for stock.  So in essence the table would be:

ID
Volume
InStockOnDate

Does anyone have some guidance?  I've been spinning on this on the back-burner for a while now.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a calendar-like table that has a contiguous date column (not related to your existing volume table), to which you add a calculated column.

The calculated column will be your stock and will be computed something like this:

```
Stock =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(VolumeTable[Volume]),
    FILTER(
        VolumeTable,
        VolumeTable[DateIn] <= StockTable[Date] &&
        VolumeTable[DateOut] > StockTable[Date]
    )
)
```

Or something along those lines. (I haven't tested this since you supplied no data to work with.)

Comment: thank you for taking the time.  Your strategy totally worked.  The only addition I made was:

`
    FILTER(
        VolumeTable,
        VolumeTable[DateIn] <= StockTable[Date] &&
        (VolumeTable[DateOut] > StockTable[Date] || VolumeTable[DateOut] = Blank())
    )
'

Comment: I'm now trying to figure out if I should make some intermediary table instead.  It'd include a row for each stock item for each day it's in stock.  This may give me the ability to filter the inventory on other items.  I'll keep you posted if it works out.